# A way to generate a universal image URL that works between Mac and iOS (DropBox, iCloud, other?)

Tags: ios, mac, icloud, markdown

I'm looking for a way to make all my markdown file universal that is work on iOS, Mac, even Linux/Window/Android.

I want to have a single folder where I stick all my images and then point to that folder from whatever OS/device I'm using. For example

```
~/img/image.png
```

would be readable in the `.md` file from anywhere.

Does anything like that exist? Can I use iCloud or Dropbox for that?  Are there any other solutions people may suggest?

Comment: Do you have a web server/cloud service where you can store all these images?

Comment: hmm not currently, but open to any suggestions. Is that possible to use it also with offline replication? Any specific servers you recommend?

Comment: It doesn't matter which one you take as long as it supports stable links and is accessible for upload/syncing from all platforms you use. What is not so clear from the question though: Do you want to access the images locally in the synced folder on each platform, or do you want to access them via the web on all platforms?

Comment: thx again. Well ideally access them via a synced folder if possible with a stable URL. I don't need a web platform as its intended to use with markdown application reading and rendering the markdown files.

Comment: I doubt that it's possible to come up with a file path which works on all systems, especially if Windows and mobile phones are involved (actually, it won't be possible with iOS). So putting everything in Dropbox or another cloud server and using a URL to access it might be the only option.

Comment: But as this is rather a cross-plattform question, do you want me to migrate it to SuperUser for you?

Comment: thx again, sure whatever you think is the proper place. TBH I mainly use Mac and iOS so would glad if that was possible for them but I think as you said even iOS and Mac won't work with stable links. Do I understand correct that one can use dropbox with URL access? If not what's a good recommended self hosted server? Thx for your kind help.

Comment: If you look for a macOS/iOS solution please edit your question to focus on this so it stays on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to have a single folder where I stick all my images and then point to that folder from whatever OS/device I'm using [and] would be readable in the `.md` file from anywhere.

What you're looking for is a cloud based service.  There are several image specific services that can do this for you:

- [Flickr/SmugMug](https://www.flickr.com/)
- [500px](https://web.500px.com/)
- [Imgur](https://imgur.com/) (used by Stack Exchange)

However, you're not limited to a service that only supports images.  iCloud (pending), DropBox, OneDrive, etc. all the ability to do what you want.  For instance, using the following markdown code, I can insert the following image hosted on my OneDrive account:

```
Code:    
<img src="https://kl8ofa.bn.files.1drv.com/y4mW66FhA4IBlnLBez4t70-rBq51PBEoTI6USX6Kxn46GjR-xfXtWz3knMJm6MbqIOwqutlneyiaDLQvj_upQgrhVjIsjQFjmHEb_DPIsIwQtzE1KD52cMyrRkZuSFQw-vJdTSkIfQfcU3IOPTj0VxC_o_Sbew8NK7I9RtUBAmfCk1NXqURe0BIVkt2-NeHQhadleH2VG0HN8e5PV3BggllSA?width=2048&height=2048&cropmode=none" width="400"
```

[image]

You can even create a download link to the [original wallpaper file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmW50NkbWLGik54_9VmMgoY8pczbzg) by using supported HTML within your markdown:

```
Code:
<a href="https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmW50NkbWLGik54_9VmMgoY8pczbzg">original wallpaper file</a>
```

Now, understand, that link *must* be generated by the service unless you plan to host the images yourself (way too much work!).

---

More Examples:

**Dropbox:**

```
Code to Embed image:
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/h29iren2akr83ii/FreeBSD%20Wallpaper%20-%20Think%20Correctly.png?raw=1 " width="400">
```

**Important note:**  To *embed* the image and not make it appear in the DropBox widget, you need to replace the `?dl=0` at the end of the URL with `?raw=1`.

[image]

```
Code:
Download link for <a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/h29iren2akr83ii/FreeBSD%20Wallpaper%20-%20Think%20Correctly.png?raw=1">Think Correctly Wallpaper</a>
```

Download link for [Think Correctly Wallpaper](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h29iren2akr83ii/FreeBSD%20Wallpaper%20-%20Think%20Correctly.png?raw=1)

**Box.Com**

Unfortunately, you can't embed an image from Box.com because their widget is incompatible with Markdown.  However, you can still share the link  [Apple Leather Desktop Walpaper](https://app.box.com/s/j68j4nvqcs9uh6zohzisws9o7evnk4kf)  like the others above.

```
Code:
<a href="https://app.box.com/s/j68j4nvqcs9uh6zohzisws9o7evnk4kf"> Apple Leather Desktop Walpaper </a>
```

---

<sup>Image Attribution.  None of these wallpapers are mine.  They are the work of the original artist and I claim no ownership.  These were sent to me or I found them in my travels on the Internet.</sup>

#### Summary

Other than the dedicated services, OneDrive and DropBox seem to have the best integration (IMO) for both embedding and linking images into a markdown document.  I'm partial to OneDrive and it's integration directly into macOS, but preferences vary.  DropBox is a bit more efficient with respect to the length of the link.  Box.com falls short in that you can't embed images but you can link to them.

Comment: allan: thx! I think your markdown code didn’t post correctly as it seems missing. Also do you have examples for dropbox or iCloud?

Comment: @zeltak I don't use dropbox, but I do I have an account.  I'll get some examples going on those as well, but it'll be roughly the same as OneDrive.

Comment: thx this is perfect!

Comment: I mis-spoke with regards to iCloud...it doesn't let you (yet) create share links.  But this does work in OneDrive, DropBox, Imgur and I believe Box.Net (I can't remember my login credentials).  As for iCloud, it's still a new feature so I'd stay away for the time being.. let them work out the bugs.